# Video stops after 2-3 secs when loaded for the first time

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I download a mp4 file from my server and try to play it.
I think the download part is not the problem, it's working. My problem is when I try to play it when the file has just been downloaded. The video plays for 2-3 seconds and then stops with the error (1 -1004) from MediaPlayer.

But when the mp4 file is already downloaded, the video play successfully.

Here is the code for the video I'm using:

```
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    Button buttonStopVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopVideo);

    // VideoView refference see main.xml
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    Log.i("Listener context path",
            "" + this.getDir("Ads", MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath());

    mVideoView.setVideoPath(srcPath);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
    if(mVideoView.isActivated() && !mVideoView.isPlaying()){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, myIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

If you have any idea, it can be really helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that I just did not finish to DL my mp4 before playing it ...